# Flex: Saving mx:image with applied effects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I load image to  control than I applie some effects, and when I save image it's saving without effects. What should i do?

Here is the code:

```
private var byteArr2:ByteArray;
private var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference(); 

public function process():void
{
        var ct:ColorTransform = new  ColorTransform();
        ct.redOffset = 99;
        ct.blueOffset = 11;
            ct.greenOffset = 22;
            currImg.transform.colorTransform = ct;
            callLater(toByteArray);
}

public function toByteArray():void
{
        var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(currImg.width, currImg.width);
        data.draw(currImg);             
        var encod:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);               
        byteArr2 = encod.encode(data);
}
public function saveFile():void 
{  
        fileRef.save(byteArr2,"NewFileName1.jpg");
} 
<mx:HBox>       
        <mx:VBox>           
            <s:Button x="69" y="98" label="open" click="open()()"/>
            <s:Button label="show" click="show()"/> 
            <s:Button label="process" click="process()"/>   
            <s:Button label="save" click="saveFile()"/> 
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:Image id="currImg" width="200" height="300"/>
    </mx:HBox>
```

**UPDATE** Appears new problem as I am using `var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(currImg.width, currImg.width);` saved image is small(size like image control) but I need to save image with original size.
With `var data:BitmapData = Bitmap(currImg.content).bitmapData;` it worked

Comment: + Well worded question and a good code sample.  Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would draw the component into a new BitmapData object rather than use the content of the currImg.  This should give you what's drawn on the screen rather than the unmodified content.  Something like so:

```
var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(currImg.width, currImg.width);
data.draw(currImg);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it's strange, but problem remains the same

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's because you are saving the image before the image updates to reflect the transform?  You could try encoding/saving in a separate method the you call using callLater which would give the image an opportunity to update first.  No guarantees, just an idea.

Comment: it's just sample code, in full version this actions are in separate methods

Comment: Do the methods get called sequentially, in other words does the event queue get emptied before the call to encode/save?  If not, callLater may still be helpful to you.

Comment: yes i using callLater for encode to byte array, and after button click save it with fileRef.save

Comment: Wow, without seeing more of your code I'm stumped.  One workaround could be to wrap your image in a container and draw that container into the bitmap instead of the image component itself.  I'm just shooting in the dark at this point though.  Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried applying a filter to the bitmapdata object after the snapshot is taken (Rather than using a transform on the image component)? A ColorMatrixFilter might do what you are trying to achieve? You can also apply the ColorTransform object to the BitmapData with BitmapData.colorTransform().

Comment: Also the JPEGncoder takes a little while to process, you might want to move that into the save file handler (remove the toByteArray call from process, move code to saveFile). Its also unclear to me when callLater gets called... if it is the next frame it might be before the rendering has been completed (so the transform is still not applied), though I always thought code executes after the rendering is complete... applying the filter to the BitmapData might avoid this issue (As it happens right away rather than the next render update)?

Comment: @Chris Bos: The callLater method basically puts the method call at the end of the event queue, which gives things a chance to update.  I thought it might help in this case since the original code Sergey posted was calling encode/save immediately after setting the transform.

Comment: @Chris Bos: when I am using filter everything works ok, but appears new problem, as I use BitmapData(currImg.width, currImg.width) saved image is small(size like image control) but I needd to save image with original size

Comment: The draw method accepts a Matrix as a optional second parameter which you should be able to use to scale. E.g. BitmapData.draw(currImg, new Matrix(2, 0, 0, 2)); //(Scale x2). Read the documentation on the draw method it explains why the transformations applied to the source will not get drawn. (It treats the source as if it was library symbol)

Comment: @Chris Bos: BitmapData.draw(currImg, new Matrix(2, 0, 0, 2)) - zooming small image not my original and image saving pixelatted.I think this is because we use (when create BitmapData) currImg.width -means width from control, but we need original image width

Comment: Yes currImg dimensions are that of the control. You need contentHeight and contentWidth for the actual non-scaled dimensions. use these values to calculate what you will need to scale. Use the smoothing option of the draw method to reduce the pixellation. Also try having a hidden control that is the actual dimensions of the loaded image (Needs to be added on the stage, but set -x, -y coordinates so it is not visible to the user). This will render you the best image to save.

Comment: @Chris Bos:hmm contentHeight and contentWidth return not original image dimension

Comment: Weird, what is the scaleX and scaleY properties on the Image control? Multiply that by the image control width/height or contentWidth/Height. You ought to get your correct values somewhere. Also I'd suggest setting the maintainAspectRatio property of the image control to true.

Answer (score 2):

Alright this isn't a great solution cause I don't know why it works but if you put a container around the image then save the results of drawing that it seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;
            private var byteArr2:ByteArray;
            private var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference(); 

            public function process():void
            {
                var ct:ColorTransform = new  ColorTransform();
                ct.redOffset = 99;
                ct.blueOffset = 11;
                ct.greenOffset = 22;
                currImg.transform.colorTransform = ct;
                callLater(toByteArray);
            }

            public function toByteArray():void
            {
                var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(everything.width, everything.width);
                data.draw(everything);             
                var encod:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);               
                byteArr2 = encod.encode(data);
            }
            public function saveFile():void 
            {  
                fileRef.save(byteArr2,"NewFileName1.jpg");
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:HBox>       
        <mx:VBox>           
            <!--<s:Button x="69" y="98" label="open" click="open()"/>-->
            <!--<s:Button label="show" click="show()"/> -->
            <s:Button label="process" click="process()"/>   
            <s:Button label="save" click="saveFile()"/> 
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:Box id="everything">
            <mx:Image id="currImg" width="200" height="300" source="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"/>
        </mx:Box>
    </mx:HBox>
</s:Application>
```

Shaun

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly but it seems that calling .colorTransform(rect,img) on the bitmap data of the content of the image also works instead of wrapping it, but it appears for whatever reason when the color transform is applied to the transform of the image it ends up somehow in it's own object that isn't a child of the image (from the documentation it reads like it would just modify the pixels of the bitmapData but it doesn't appear this is the case)